# how can I get the 'extra' bar on icons to stop coming up?

Tags: kubuntu

On Kubuntu 14.04, I have icons on my desktop. When I hover my mouse over them for even a split second, the little bar comes up which lets me resize, etc. How do I keep that bar from coming up?

Answer (score 0):

Try to lock your Dekstop Widgets.
Right click on Desktop and choose "Lock widgets".

This should solve your problem.

found here: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/483460-Show-Hide-KDE-icon-handles